# Creating LinkedIn test accounts

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

In section 2.3 of LinkedIn's Terms of Use for their API (https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), they mention that developers may create up to 5 accounts for testing and that these accounts must be created manually.

I created 5 accounts with the last names "Test-User" that all had email accounts for my company. I listed these accounts as Developers under the Application Roles settings of my LinkedIn application. I began using them for testing (testing consisted of logging in via OAUTH 2.0, renewing tokens, and making test posts), but within 24 hours the test accounts were all locked down for "suspicious activity."

Is there anything I missed when creating test users? LinkedIn's documentation on creating them as far as I have been able to find consists only of what's listed in the Terms of Use doc. Does anyone know if any other documentation exists?

Do I need to join a Partnership Program with LinkedIn in order to have test accounts? https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member accounts where "Test" is used in the name are likely to be removed by our spam filters.

Comment: Ok...thanks! I'll create some new users with different names and try again.

Comment: Well, this time the test accounts lasted for a few days...but they've been flagged as restricted again. This is a very frustrating issue for developers trying to integrate with LinkedIn.

Comment: Be aware of this: "You may create LinkedIn test profiles to test your Application, provided that they do not interact with real Members or company or other organization pages on LinkedIn."